# How to get better error messages when parsing JSON with Argonaut and custom codecs

Tags: scala, argonaut

I'm using Argonaut to parse JSON with my custom codecs. My code looks like this:

```
val json: String = ...
val parsed = Parse.decodeEither[MyClass](json)
val checks = if (parsed.isRight) parsed.right.get
else sys.error("Unable to parse MyClass json: " + parsed.left)
```

However, I never get any useful error messages. All I get is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse MyClass json: LeftProjection(Left(String: CursorHistory(List())))`.

What is the proper way to handle decoding errors?

**Edit**: my question is not what to do with the provided error message. It would be *great* if Argonaut could say something like "Parsing error at position X, unexpected member y" or something like that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether I understand what your actual question is...

You are getting `Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse MyClass json: LeftProjection(Left(String: CursorHistory(List())))` because that's what `sys.error` does.

When you use the method `Parse.decodeEither`, the resulting type is an `Either[String, MyClass]`. There are many ways to check or operate with an Either. One of them, you are already using: Inspecting whether the result is on either side and act based on it.

A more idiomatic approach though, would be to fold over it:

```
parsed.fold(
    error => //do something with error,
    myclass => //do something with myclass
)
```

From Scala 2.12, `Either` is right biased Monad, which means that you can use it in a for comprehension that will flatMap over the right hand side.
I think reading its [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html) could be of help.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand much of what you say. What I say is that I don't know if there is a way to get a more useful error message from Argonaut. When the parsing succeeds, everything is good and dandy; but when parsing fails, I don't have a clue where or what the error is about. That's my question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Argonaut decode errors can be a bit terse, but they are meaningful too. Pay attention to the [CursorHistory](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/blob/series/6.2.x/argonaut/shared/src/main/scala/argonaut/CursorHistory.scala) object. It provides the most recent operation during decoding.

In your case, it looks like you're unable to parse the JSON since `CursorHistory` is an empty `List`.

Simple Example (not tested):

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
  implicit def PersonCodecJson: CodecJson[Person] =
    casecodec2(Person.apply, Person.unapply)("name", "age")
}
```

Person JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Fred"
}
```

The error parsing the example above would be something like: `CursorHistory(List(El(CursorOpDownField(age),false)))`.

Comment: "A bit terse" is quite an understatement. My JSON file is several thousand lines long, and I get it from a third-party producer. They changed something but I cannot find out what.